# non-static variable username cannot be referenced from a static content

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors, non-static

I've written this test code:

```
        try {            
            com.mysql.jdbc.Connection koneksi = (com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.51/db_apps_ad", "root", "");
            koneksi.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tbl_presensi VALUES (NULL,'"
                    + getCurrentDateTime() + "',NULL,NULL'"
                    + getIPAddress() + "','"                    
                    + username.getText() + "')");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But it gives the following error:

non-static variable username cannot be referenced from a static content
in line "+ username.getText() + "')");"

How do I get my methods to recognize my class variables?

I have tried creating a string object with the name String username = username.getText(); in the main method. Then called him by username but still didn't work. I hope your friends' answers can solve my program

Comment: Remove the word `static` from the method that has the code that you've shown.  That will most likely move the error message to somewhere else - at some point, you're going to have to instantiate this class, if you're going to use its non-static fields.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. Also, why are you casting to `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection`? You should be using `java.sql.Connection` (the return type of  `DriverManager.getConnection`). Additionally, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: you should never concatenate values into a query string: use a [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with parameters.